# Atom text editor: keyboard shortcut for lining up text?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm looking for a shortcut to line up text to the nearest tab if all the lines have white space. Allow me to give an example:

```
select    a |as Alpha,
          bbbbb |as Beta,
          ccc |as Chi
```

Now lets assume my cursor is before all the `as` and is represented by the `|` above.

I'd if I press tab I get this:

```
select    a     |as Alpha,
          bbbbb     |as Beta,
          ccc     |as Chi
```

I would prefer, however, to have a keyboard shortcut that does this:

```
select    a     |as Alpha,
          bbbbb |as Beta,
          ccc   |as Chi
```

Does such a thing exist in the atom universe? I've searched to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://atom.io/packages/alignment This should work for what you want. Not sure if there is a shortcut but at least a right click option should exist.

Edit: There is a keyboard shortcut to align.